# Create a 900x900 matrix and diagonalize it

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have to create a 900x900 matrix and then diagonalize it. It is something similar to the below matrix. The value of a,b,c,d....up to 900 values (which are the first column and row) are the number. The pattern of calculation the rest elements of the matrix is showing here (here I take an example of multiplying 3x3 matrix. the first element is a*a and so on). On top of my head, I can use Excel to calculate but it is gonna take me a long long time. Do you guys have any suggestions about the method of doing it more effectively? I would really appreciate it.

```
{{state, a, b, c}, 
 {a, a*a, a*b, a*c}, 
 {b, b*a, b*b, b*c}, 
 {c, c*a, c*b, c*c}}
```

Comment: One possibility: `Outer[Times, {state, a, b, c}, {state, a, b, c}] /. {state^2 -> state,
   state -> 1}` Only works if you don't yet have numbers, but it can be adapted. Can we get more information about the entries? Are they symbolic? NUmeric? Etc.

Comment: It looks as if your matrix will have at most rank 2.  It should be possible to generate a symbolic diagonalisation for it without ever building the full matrix.  It might help if you explain what you plan to do with the diagonalised form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Times:

```
avec = Array[a, 4];
m = Outer[Times, avec, avec] /. {a[1] -> 1};
m[[1, 1]] = s;
MatrixForm[m]
Eigenvalues[m]
```

[image]

Here a[2] is your a, a[3] is your b, etc. Change the 4 to 900 if you wish. There are two nonzero eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any way that I can import the value of a[n] (n from 1 to 900) from Excel. As far as I understand, for you method, I have to assign each value for a[1], a[2]...up to 900 step be step, haven't I?

Comment: Import from an excel file using `Import`.

Comment: yeah I know how to import it into mathematica but how to assign these 900 numbers to a[1], a[2], a[3]....a[n] at the same time instead of edit it one by one?

Comment: say your imported data is a length 900 list called dat. Then you can assign: `Table[a[i] = dat[[i]], {i, 900}]`

Comment: One note for OP, if you're using this code, make sure you `ClearAll[a]` before running it and then assign values after `m[[1, 1]] = s`. Not clearing `a` might cause the `ReplaceAll (/.)` to replace wrong values.

Comment: I create a random excel file to test it as below how ever when trying to do as Bill suggestion:

test = Import["Documents/test.xlsx"];
Table[a[i] = test[[i]], {i, 6}]

 I have errors like this:
Part 2 of {{{2.5},{6.5},{2.5},{5.},{6.},{0.3}}} does not exist. >>
Part 3 of {{{2.5`},{6.5`},{2.5`},{5.`},{6.`},{0.3`}}} does not exist. \
>>
Part 4 of {{{2.5},{6.5},{2.5},{5.},{6.},{0.3}}} does not exist. >>

Comment: @QuangPhan Try `test = Flatten[Import["Documents/test.xlsx"]]`. There is an extra `List` for some reason.

Comment: @quangphan The question of importing from an excel file is good and relevant enough that you should post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 6):

```
yourlist = {a, b, c};
mat = ReplacePart[Outer[Times, #, #]&@Prepend[yourlist, 1], {1, 1} -> state]
```

[image]

Change `yourlist` to the list of your interest.

Or, taking @mikado 's idea of symbolically diagonalizing:

```
matfunc[1, 1] = state;
matfunc[1, a_Integer] := yourlist[[a - 1]];
matfunc[a_Integer, 1] := yourlist[[a - 1]];
matfunc[a_Integer, b_Integer] := yourlist[[a - 1]] yourlist[[b - 1]];
```

Answer (score 1):

The matrix desired is at most rank two and can be easily expressed as the product of a matrix and its transpose.  I will number the elements for convenience and assume that `state > 1` (otherwise we have imaginary elements, which would require further thought).

```
n = 3;
v1 = Prepend[Array[a, n], 1];
v2 = Prepend[Array[0 &, n], Sqrt[state - 1]];
M1 = Transpose[{v1, v2}];
```

The desired matrix is given by

```
M = M1.Transpose[M1]

(* {{state, a[1],      a[2],       a[3]},
    {a[1],  a[1]^2,    a[1] a[2],  a[1] a[3]},
    {a[2],  a[1] a[2], a[2]^2,     a[2] a[3]},
    {a[3],  a[1] a[3], a[2] a[3],  a[3]^2}} *)
```

This can then be diagonalised.  Symbolically this is messy so for the demonstration I will assume some arbitrary values:

```
testcase = {state -> 13., a[i_] -> i^2 - 7.};
```

The matrix `M1` can be factorised using

```
{U, S, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[M1 /. testcase, 2];
```

giving `M1 == U.S.Transpose[V]` (for real `V`).  Note that `U` and `V` are orthonormal and `S` is diagonal,  so that `M == M1.Transpose[M1] == U.(S.S).Transpose[U]` is the diagonalisation.

This can be verified by evaluating

```
U.(S.S).Transpose[U] - M /. testcase // Chop
(* {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}} *)
```